# Why is my JTextField not saving the input properly?

Tags: java, oop, jtextfield

I am still new to coding and I am trying to finish my high school Java exit project. What I have is compiling and running, but the bug is that when I ask it to print off the separately inputted information, the most recent entrance saves over the first entrances.

I have it so that within the frame there are text fields to input information about students. Once you click next, the information *should* save, the text fields clear and it would be ready for new information. I have it set up this way so it can repeat for an inputted amount of students.

Here's where I save the text field input:

```
o[one.getRepeatCount()] = new Student(sFirst.getText(), sLast.getText(), sHr.getText(), Integer.parseInt(sId.getText()), Integer.parseInt(sAverage.getText()));
System.out.println(o[one.getRepeatCount()].first);
o[one.getRepeatCount()].addToList();
```

And here's the Student class, which is where the text field information should be saved:

```
class Student{//Student constructor class
    public static String first; private static String last; private String hr; private static String newString; //declaring strings
    private static String strLast; private static String strFirst; private static String comma = ", ";//declaring more strings
    private int id; private int n=0; private static int j=0; private static int studentTot;//declaring ints
    private double avg;//declaring double variable
    public static Student[] studentList; public static JLabel[] labels;//declaring arrays

    public static void setStudentTot(int inTot){
        studentTot = inTot;
    }

    public static int getStudentTot(){
        return studentTot;
    }

    public static void createList(){
        studentList = new Student[studentTot];
        labels = new JLabel[studentTot];
    }

    Student(String firstIn, String lastIn, String hrIn, int idIn, double avgIn){//student constructor method
        first=firstIn;
        last=lastIn;
        hr=hrIn;
        id=idIn;
        avg=avgIn;
    }

    public void addToList(){ // Student.addToList();
        studentList[n]= new Student(first,last,hr,id,avg);
        n++;
    }

    public static void createLabel(){
        System.out.println(j);
        labels[j] = new JLabel(studentList[j].last+", "+studentList[j].first);
        System.out.println(last+", "+first);
        labels[j].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        labels[j].setBounds(75,30*j+25, 500,25);//(x,y, width,height)                               
        j++;
    }
}
```

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: All the static variables and method would seem to indicate a design problem. Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. I would use an ArrayList to store each Student. An ArrayList is easier to use than an Array since you don't need to use a fixed size.

Comment: @camickr Thank you. I ended up bringing the code to someone with more experience and we worked out that, yeah, the static variables didn't help. Also, thank you for telling me about ArrayLists. We didn't cover those in class but they seem a lot simpler to use for future projects. :)